# Getting simple epic working in redux-observable

Tags: redux, react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

Trying to implement my first simple `epic` using `redux-observable` but running into two issues:

1. After I hit my break point, I get an error that reads "Cannot read property 'closed' of undefined" and after that I don't hit the break point in my `epic` -- see below [image]
2. Once I hit my `epic`, I want to `dispatch` `myAction` which is an action creator. Not sure how to add `dispatch`. Initially, I didn't add anything and got dispatch not defined error. Then I noticed that my IDE automatically added `import { dispatch } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/pairs';`. Not sure if this is the way to add `dispatch` to my `epic`. This could also be the reason for the error.

The fact that I'm initially hitting my `epic` when a particular action is fired, tells me that it's successfully added into the middleware pipeline but clearly something is not right.

Here's what my epic looks like:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { filter, map, mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { dispatch } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/pairs'; // ??? Is this how I access dispatch?

import * as types from '../../actions/action-types';
import { myAction} from '../../actions/my-actions';

export const mySimpleEpic = (action$, state$) => action$.pipe(

    ofType(types.SOMETHING_HAS_HAPPENED),
    map(() => {
        debugger
        dispatch(myAction("Hello World!"))
    })
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epics don't `dispatch` actions, they `emit` actions. It's `redux-observable` who dispatches the actions emitted from your epics. The basic epic structure should be something like:

```
export const mySimpleEpic = action$ => 
    action$
    .ofType(types.SOMETHING_HAS_HAPPENED)
    .map(() => myAction("Hello World!"));
```

Comment: I see but could use a bit more clarification. `myAction` in my example is an action creator so I need to use `dispatch` to call it. How do I import `dispatch`? Is the way it's imported in the code in original post correct? Also, still getting the error. Any ideas why?

Comment: No you don't need dispatch, you emmit what the action creator returns, `redux-observable` will dispatch it for you.

Comment: Thanks again but I think this is the learning curve everyone's talking about :-) I tried just calling `myAction("Hello World");` without `dispatch` as in your answer, I then got errors in another middleware I have in my app stating that `type` was undefined. Confused what's going on here. Is `redux-observable` not dispatching it for me or chances are I'm making a mistake because this is not yet clear.

Comment: I'm looking at the example here: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html They show `// later... dispatch(myAction());` Not sure what later means! I also tried creating another function outside of my `epic` which will `dispatch` my action creator so I call that function from my `epic` but that just seems unnecessary code and I still get the error that I mentioned in original post.

Comment: OK! I got it! Thank you! It is true that there's a learning curve because it requires different way of thinking.

Comment: Yeah `redux-observable` is difficult; elegant, terse, sort and powerful -- but difficult.